# Programming absolute deviation as linear program

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, scipy-optimize

I am attempting to convert a sum of absolute deviations to a linear programming problem so that I can utilize CPLEX (or other solver). I am stuck on how the matrices are to be set up. The problem is as follows:

```
minimize abs(x1 - 5) + abs(x2 - 3)
s.t. x1 + x2 = 10
```

I have the following constraints set up to transform the problem into a linear form:

```
  x1 - 5  <= t1
-(x1 - 5) <= t1 and 

  x2 - 3  <= t2
-(x2 - 3) <= t2
```

I've set up the objective function as

```
c = [0,0,1,1]
```

but I am lost on how to set up

```
Ax <= b
```

in matrix form. What I have so far is:

```
A = [[ 1, -1, 0, 0],
     [-1, -1, 0, 0],
     [ 0,  0, 1,-1],
     [ 0,  0,-1,-1]]
b =  [ 5, -5, 3,-3]
```

I have set up the other constraint in matrix for as:

```
B =  [1, 1, 0, 0]
b2 = [10]
```

When I run the following:

```
linprog(c,A_ub=A,b_ub=b,A_eq=B,b_eq=b2,bounds=[(0,None),(0,None)])
```

I get the following error message back:

```
ValueError: Invalid input for linprog: A_eq must have exactly two dimensions, and the number of columns in A_eq must be equal to the size of c
```

I know there is a solution because when I use scipy.optimize.minimize it solves to [6,4]. I'm sure the issue is I am not formulating the input matrices correctly but I am not sure how to set them up so that it runs.

Edit - here is the code that does not run:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog, minimize

c = np.block([np.zeros(2),np.ones(2)])
print("c =>",c)

A = [[ 1, -1, 0, 0],
     [-1, -1, 0, 0],
     [ 0,  0, 1,-1],
     [ 0,  0,-1,-1]]

b =  [[ 5, -5, 3,-3]]
print(A)
print(np.multiply(A,b))

B = [ 1, 1, 0, 0]
b2 = [10]
print(np.multiply(B,b2))

linprog(c,A_ub=A,b_ub=b,A_eq=B,b_eq=b2,bounds=[(0,None),(0,None)],
        options={'disp':True})
```

Comment: What modules are you importing?  Set tags accordingly.  Be more explicit about the problem setup (real code, not just objects that look just like Python lists).  Full traceback on that error.

Comment: hpaulj - done. See above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the message is quite good. `B` should be 2-dimensional matrix instead of a 1-dimensional vector. So:

```
B =  [[1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Secondly, the bounds array is too short.
Thirdly, your ordering of variables is inconsistent. The columns in `A` are `x1,t1,x2,t2` while the columns in B (and c) seem to be `x1,x2,t1,t2`. They need to follow the same scheme.

Comment: Thanks Erwin - after incorporating your suggestions, the program was successful. One question - A is arranged [[x1, -t1, 0, 0],[-x1, -t1, 0, 0],[0, 0, x2, -t2],[0, 0, -x2, -t2]]. Is this not correct?

Comment: No. There are only constants in A. And the ordering of the columns should be the same in A, B and c.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what you mean by the order of the columns in A. If I want the columns in A to be ```(x1, x2, t1, t2)``` the matrix should be ```[[1, 0, -1, 0],[-1, 0, -1, 0],[0, 1, 0, -1],[0, -1, 0, -1]]``` and b should be ```[5, -5, 3, -3]``` correct?